# Selenium - Unable to click element on page from Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath

I am unable to click on the 'Odds' tab on the following page using Selenium:
https://www.flashscore.dk/kamp/zFfSWY7h/#kampreferat

Currently my code is the followig:

```
from selenium import webdriver                                      # General webscraping
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By                         # Specification of method for locating elements
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait             # Waiting for element to load
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC    # Expected conditions (used for waits)
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)                     # Use the chrome webdriver
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)                     # Will wait for up to 10 seconds for an element/page to load

# URL of webpage to scrape from
web = 'https://www.flashscore.dk/kamp/zFfSWY7h/#kampreferat'

# Open webpage
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
driver.get(web)

# Go to Odds
odds_page = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="a-match-odds-comparison"]')
odds_page.click()
```

I have tried to use the wait-function (WebDriverWait) but I cannot seem to make it work and even if i let the page sleep for 120 seconds it will give me an error:

```
Exception has occurred: NoSuchElementException
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="a-match-odds-comparison"]"}
```

I have also tried to use `driver.find_element_by_id('[@id="a-match-odds-comparison')` also with any luck.

Any advice on how to improve and fix the code would be greatly appreciated.

My final goal is to go through each sub-tab on the odds page and scrape alle the odds for each bookmaker.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try. It waits for the element on the screen to load. In your case it waits for the "odds" tab to be visible.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='path')            
waitshort = WebDriverWait(driver,.5)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
waitLonger = WebDriverWait(driver, 100)
visible = EC.visibility_of_element_located         # Use the chrome webdriver              # Will wait for up to 10 seconds for an element/page to load
driver.get('https://www.flashscore.dk/kamp/zFfSWY7h/#kampreferat')
odds = wait.until(visible((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="a-match-odds-comparison"]'))).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get('https://www.flashscore.dk/kamp/zFfSWY7h/#kampreferat')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="a-match-odds-comparison"]'))).click()
```

Just wait for the element to be clickable and click it.

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```